# How do I prevent Enigmail from encrypting my email, even when encryption is turned off?

Tags: email, encryption, thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

Enigmail add-on to Thunderbird is encrypting all emails, even when encryption is turned off.

[image: edit window]

I save the email as a draft, and when I view it in Drafts folder (or if it was sent), then it shows as blank and encrypted! I even restarted Thunderbird without luck.

[image: drafts folder]

Enigmail 1.8.2, Thunderbird 31.7.0

Comment: Does that recipient have an encryption key?  If you do a draft email to some who you don't have a public key for, then that message will not be encrypted right?

Comment: No, the recipient does not have an encryption key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Tools > Account Settings > your account > Open PGP Settings > Turn off 'Encrypt Draft Messages on Saving'

[image]