# Encryption of drafts in the new Thunderbird with integrated Enigmail

Tags: email, encryption, thunderbird

Is it possible to disable the encryption of drafts in the new Thunderbird 78.5.0 with integrated Enigmail while keeping OpenPGP activated?
The answer provided [here](https://superuser.com/questions/972285/how-do-i-prevent-enigmail-from-encrypting-my-email-even-when-encryption-is-turn) seems to be no longer valid.
Thanks!

EDIT: I edited the settings manually as it was suggested below, but the problem still persists.

[image]

EDIT2: Here are my settings containing "crypt"

[image]

[image]

EDIT 3: It seems to be a known unsolved bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1681168). A hacky solution by editing Thunderbird's omni.ja file is proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [bug was resolved](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1681168#a15799606_36541) in Thunderbird 91.

`mail.identity.default.autoEncryptDrafts` is now honored and there is even an option in the graphical settings of each account, that sets `mail.identity.id<insert number here>.autoEncryptDrafts` which overwrites `….default.…` for that account.

Go to …

1. Edit
2. Account Settings
3. mymailaddress@host.tld
4. End-to-End Encryption
5. Uncheck "*Store draft messages in encrypted format*"

[image: Screenshot: Disable encrypted drafts]

Above screenshot was taken in in Thunderbird 91.20.0, but is still up to date for Thunderbird 120.2.0.

Comment: Strange, I can´t find the "End-to-End Encryption" Section, although I have seen it before. Could you provide screenshots for the path to this setting?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the configuration option `autoencryptdrafts`. Open the `Config Editor`, search for `autoencryptdrafts` and change it's value to false.

Comment: I did it but the problem persist! More info: My private key is stored on a Yubikey. Thunderbird still wants me to insert it whenever I try to open a draft.

Comment: You mean a newly created draft I suppose, after you made the config change?

Comment: Yes, a newly created draft. I even restarted the computer after making the change.

Comment: I don't think I can find a straightforward solution to this except the one I gave you. it works for me, is all I can say. You could go through the config editor options using the `crypt` keyword, and try playing with the `true/false` or `0/1` values. I suspect one of them will be the right one.

Comment: It is really strange, thanks for helping me! Please, see the screenshot of my "crypt" settings.

Comment: I have the same issue, since upgrading Ubuntu from 20.10 to 21.4, and thuinderbird 78.11.0 (didn't check what the previous version was). I have verified that autoencryptDrafts is set to false, but still all drafts get encrypted.